# Having metrics from opentelemetry nodejs library scraped (or pushed)

Tags: node.js, kubernetes, monitoring, metrics, open-telemetry

I am using [GrowthBook](https://docs.growthbook.io/) which has recently [introduced](https://github.com/growthbook/growthbook/pull/1441/files) OTEL.

Everything is running on my platform on Kubernetes

I see that the only thing that is done in that context is to import the corresponding [@opentelemetry/auto-instrumentations-node library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@opentelemetry/auto-instrumentations-node).

Before using it, I was also advised to set the `OTEL_EXPORTER_OTLP_ENDPOINT` environment variable to an appropriate endpoint where the metrics could be pushed.

I have a `prometheus-pushgateway` running an exposed as an internal k8s service.

I tried setting `OTEL_EXPORTER_OTLP_ENDPOINT: http://prometheus-pushgateway:9091/metrics`

The process fails and the logs indicate:

```
Process is not running on K8S Error: Failed to load page, status code: 403
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/usr/local/src/app/node_modules/@opentelemetry/resource-detector-aws/build/src/detectors/AwsEksDetector.js:192:32)
    at /usr/local/src/app/node_modules/@opentelemetry/context-async-hooks/build/src/AbstractAsyncHooksContextManager.js:50:55
    at AsyncLocalStorage.run (node:async_hooks:319:14)
    at AsyncLocalStorageContextManager.with (/usr/local/src/app/node_modules/@opentelemetry/context-async-hooks/build/src/AsyncLocalStorageContextManager.js:33:40)
    at IncomingMessage.contextWrapper (/usr/local/src/app/node_modules/@opentelemetry/context-async-hooks/build/src/AbstractAsyncHooksContextManager.js:50:32)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (node:events:525:35)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (node:domain:489:12)
    at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1358:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21)


{"stack":"OTLPExporterError: Not Found\n    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/usr/local/src/app/node_modules/@opentelemetry/otlp-exporter-base/build/src/platform/node/util.js:103:39)\n    at /usr/local/src/app/node_modules/@opentelemetry/context-async-hooks/build/src/AbstractAsyncHooksContextManager.js:50:55\n    at AsyncLocalStorage.run (node:async_hooks:319:14)\n    at AsyncLocalStorageContextManager.with (/usr/local/src/app/node_modules/@opentelemetry/context-async-hooks/build/src/AsyncLocalStorageContextManager.js:33:40)\n    at IncomingMessage.contextWrapper (/usr/local/src/app/node_modules/@opentelemetry/context-async-hooks/build/src/AbstractAsyncHooksContextManager.js:50:32)\n    at IncomingMessage.emit (node:events:525:35)\n    at IncomingMessage.emit (node:domain:489:12)\n    at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1358:12)\n    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21)","message":"Not Found","name":"OTLPExporterError","data":"404 page not found\n","code":"404"}
```

At the same time, I noticed that perhaps OTEL export is not [compatible](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-js/issues/1278) with `prometheus-pushgateway` ?

My questions are the following:

- Does the above library import makes the metrics available at a specific endpoint or are they pushed somewhere?
- If they are pushed, what might be the cause behind the above failure?

From within a pod in the cluster, a `$ curl https://prometheus-pushgateway:9091/metrics` seems to be successful FWIW.

I have also tried setting `OTEL_EXPORTER_OTLP_ENDPOINT: http://prometheus-pushgateway:9091` (i.e. without the `/metrics` path but the error remains the same.

Answer (score 0):

The pushgateway does not support OTLP ingestion but Prometheus itself does. You'll need to use the `otlp-write-receiver` feature flag enabled on your prometheus instance to make that work. You can read more about that [here](https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/pull/12643/files). Another option is to send to an otel collector and use either the [prometheusexporter](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector-contrib/tree/main/exporter/prometheusexporter) or [prometheusremotewriteexporter](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector-contrib/tree/main/exporter/prometheusremotewriteexporter) components.

The pushgateway should only be used for short lived jobs where there is not a long enough interval for prometheus to scrape metrics. ([read more docs here](https://prometheus.io/docs/practices/pushing/))

Comment: Thanks. So in the setting I described, the metrics are not exposed by the Growthbook service but are being sent somewhere? i.e. they cannot be scraped, right?

Comment: In this case your metrics are being sent via OTLP to the push-gateway which is just rejecting them